How to connect to another computer with postgress database with vb.net forms
Hello im super new to programming.
Is all i need to connect to a database on a different computer its connection string from the guys who owns the computer? or are there any more stuff i need to do or wirte in vb.net
Context:
Im making a winform app. but the data i need to access is in another computer with a postgre database. When i was talking to the dude about how to connect to his end. he just told me he can open a port but i dont really get what he means by that and as he was busy i couldnt ask.
Prior to this i've just been doing my database in my local computer. Is the port he's talking about related to the connection string i usually use which has my ip and stuff. Do i just need to ask him for a connection string?
thank you.
dont know where to start

Is the remote database on the same LAN? (N.B. Never expose a database directly to the internet because it will be hacked.)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Step 1: Install Npgsql Library then install the Npgsql Package via NuGet (Go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution). Then Search for "Npgsql" and install it.
Step 2: Create a Connection String using details such as (Host, Port, Database Name, Username & Password)
Step 3: Write VB.Net Code to Connect & Query the database
Step 4: Configure PostgreSQL for Remote Access (edit postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf)
Step 5: Restart PostgreSQL to apply the changes.
